# How do I correctly utilize python lists in dynamic routing for a web framework?

Tags: python, list, dynamic, frameworks, routes

I'm getting a "list index out of range error" in line 9 for key = re.findall(etc)[0] and I'm not sure why. What I'm attempting to do is... For the routing if I gave a route "/user//"   I could then run the regular expression re.findall(r"<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)>", url)  which would return the list ['', ''] so then I could put in my routing table {'/user' : ['name', 'page_num']}  and if the url '/user/Kyle/237' is typed into the browser I can see that /user is in the routing table and it can have 2 more things provided so since after /user in the url requested there are 2 things 'Kyle' and '237', So in my method I would have made 2 parameters 'name' and 'page_num' and I can see that name was first in the route so name=Kyle and page_num was second so page_num=237 and pass those to my method that will format and return the template page.

The framework:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from wsgiref.util import setup_testing_defaults
import re

routing_table = {}

def route(url, func):
   params =  re.findall(r"<([a-zA-Z_][0-9]*)>", url)
   key = re.findall(r"(.+?)/<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*>", url)[0]
   routing_table[key] = [params, func]

def find_path(url):
   if url in routing_table:
      return routing_table[url]
   else:
      return None

# This function is called each time the web server receives a request.
def app(environ, start_response):
   setup_testing_defaults(environ)
   handler = find_path(environ['PATH_INFO'])
   if handler is None:
      status = '404 Not Found'
      body = "<html><body><h1>Page Not Found</h1></body></html>"
   else:
      status = '200 OK'
      body = handler()  #<--- call handler
   headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')]
   start_response(status, headers)
   return [body.encode("utf-8")]

def run(ip, port):
   myserver = make_server(ip, port, app)
   print("Serving glasses of wsgi at http://%s:%s" % (ip, port))
   myserver.serve_forever()
```

The app:

```
import glass

def index():
   return "This is the main page"

def hello():
   return "hi, how are you?"

def page(page_id):
   return "this is page %d" % page_id

def user(name, page_id):
    return "Hello %d! This happens to be page %d" % name, page_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
   glass.route("/", index)
   glass.route("/hello", hello)
   glass.route("/page/<page_id>", page)
   glass.route("/user/<name>/<page_id>", user)

   glass.run("127.0.0.1", 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, this regex "(.+?)/<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*>" is only looking for a url that has this format:

/route/

if you have this:

/route

will fail. So, in the two firsts, re.findall() will return an empty list. And then you fail to get index [0] from the list.

What you can do is change this:

```
key = re.findall(r"(.+?)/<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*>", url)[0]
```

for this:

```
key = url
for param in params:
    key = key.replace("/{0}".format(param),'')
```

The logic is: you replace all params inside the url (/) for an empty string. At the end you will have just your key (/route).

Comment: Yeah, but it's still not dynamically routing like I need. This did fix the list index out of range error, though. But still, when I type into the URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/user/whoever/23, the screen is supposed to dynamically route the parameters through the functions.

Comment: What is the value of environ['PATH_INFO']? What is the format? Because, it seems that this line "if url in routing_table" is strange.